# Edit shared resources settings via console

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share

In short, i have network of 15 PCs and one server with shared resources. The problem is that when i try to access resource, i am prompted to enter password. How could i disable that? And one more: because I have only console access to the server, how can I change that via console. `Windows 2008 Server Enterprice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use "cacls" from the command prompt to grant permissions to files and shared resources on the server.  The command line will depend on what you are granting permission to as well as which users/groups you are granting permission to.